# Dynamically insert foreignObject into svg with jquery

Tags: jquery, svg

Given this html+svg

```
<div id="svg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="300" height="300">
        <svg x='10' y='10' id='group'>
           <rect id="rect" x='0' y='0' width='100' height='100'  fill='#f0f0f0'/>
        </svg>
        <svg x='100' y='100' id='group2'>
           <rect id="rect2" x='0' y='0' width='100' height='100' fill='#f00000'/>
           <foreignobject x='0' y='0' width='100' height='100' >
                <body>
                    <div>manual</div>
                </body>
           </foreignobject>
        </svg>
    </svg>
</div>
```

I'd like to insert a foreignObject into #group (preferably with jquery for it makes manipulation simpler). I've tried(code is sketchy from head)

```
$("#group").append("<foreignobject x='0' y='0' width='100' height='100'><body><div>auto</div></body></foreignobject>")
```

to no avail probably because "body" gets stripped. I've tried several exotic ways of creating the body element and the best I could - firebug doesn't grey out the inserted foreignObject element anymore but it's still not visible.

So either I'm not seeing something obvious or there's a strange way to do that.

Ideas?

**Update with final solution**
This is the shortest of what I came up with

```
var foreignObject = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject' );
var body = document.createElement( 'body' ); // you cannot create bodies with .apend("<body />") for some reason
$(foreignObject).attr("x", 0).attr("y", 0).attr("width", 100).attr("height", 100).append(body);
$(body).append("<div>real auto</div>");
$("#group").append(foreignObject);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SVG is case sensitive and the element name you want is called foreignObject. To create it using the dom you would call

```
document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject')
```

Comment: both firefox and chrome permit case insensitive svg tags - at least code above shows manually defined foreign object

Answer (score -1):

jQuery is not well suited for SVG documents.

But you still could use plain JS in connection with jQuery:

```
var foreignObject = document.createElement( 'foreignobject' );

/* add further child elements and attributes to foreignObject */

document.getElementById( 'group' ).appendChild( foreignObject );
```

Comment: this rather verbose piece of code still displays nothing

`var foreignObject = document.createElement('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject');
foreignObject.setAttribute("x", "0");
foreignObject.setAttribute("y", "0");
foreignObject.setAttribute("width", "100");
foreignObject.setAttribute("height", "100");

    
var body = document.createElement( 'body' );
var div = document.createElement( 'div' );
var text = document.createTextNode("auto");

div.appendChild(text);
body.appendChild(div);
foreignObject.appendChild(body);
document.getElementById( 'group' ).appendChild( foreignObject );`

Comment: document.createElement should be document.createElementNS

Comment: document.CreateElementNS requires two arguments, not only the element you want to create but also 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'